# Check if a variable is defined in django templating language

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am using django 1.5, I need to check if a variable is defined (and have it not work if the variable is defined but None, 0, "", etc...). Something like:

```
{% ifexists a_variable %}
    <p> Hey the variable exists </p>
{% endifexists %}
```

I don't how best to do this...

Comment: This seems like a reasonable question to me about how to tell the difference between a variable which is set to something false in the context and a variable which is not set at all. It's certainly not off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#if).

> The {% if %} tag evaluates a variable, and if that variable is “true”
>   (i.e. exists ...

```
{% if athlete_list %}
    Number of athletes: {{ athlete_list|length }}
{% elif athlete_in_locker_room_list %}
    Athletes should be out of the locker room soon!
 {% else %}
    No athletes.
{% endif %}
```

You might also want to check out the rather handy Django tutorial for [writing public views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something).

Comment: surely if athlete_list was set to [] or None it would go to the else? That's not what I want, I need it so that I can tell if a variable is set (see http://codepad.org/OJbkRWYN)

Comment: @Cucwx Why are you sending possibly unset variables to the template? Either way, if a variable is invalid (unset), Django will set it to the value of `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID`, you could set this to be something else and then check whether `person` or `coach` is equal to that; see [Invalid template variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables). Although this is not really a good idea (as expressed by the doc itself).

Comment: @SamStudio8's comment should replace the answer as it's more useful.