# Check if variable exists in template, without causing errors in loggers if it doesn't

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have enabled `'level': 'DEBUG'` in `LOGGING` in `settings.py`.

I'm aware that the proposed solutions to check if a variable exists, in a template, is using the if template tag

```
{% if variable %}
```

This is proposed in the documentation and [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671458/check-if-a-variable-is-defined-in-django-templating-language/17671642#17671642) asking how to check if a variable exists are closed as off-topic and pointed in that direction.

Another solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924865/how-to-check-if-django-template-variable-is-defined) is to compare with None.

```
{$ if variable is not None %}
```

however, in both cases, although it works fine on the user end, the logger saves that as a `KeyError`, cluttering my log files.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the log level for the logger named `django.template` to `INFO` or higher to disable these log messages.

Comment: In this case you will skip all really meaning error in your template

Answer (score 0):

I use django filters to solve this issue correctly:

In `myapp/templatetags/filters.py` I add:

```py
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def var_exists(context, name):
    dicts = context.dicts  # array of dicts
    if dicts:
        for d in dicts:
            if name in d:
                return True
    return False
```

In html template:

```html
{% load filters %}
...
{% var_exists 'project' as project_exists %}
{% if project_exists %}
  ...
{% endif}
```